# Tkinter - mouse coursor does not visibly change when programatically changed using context manager in MVC pattern

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, model-view-controller

**Tkinter - mouse coursor does not change on the screen when changed using context manager in MVC pattern.**

I tried to make na application using MVC pattern and tkinter library. To make controller states more comfortable to manage I tried to use context manager and @property decorator to manage contoller state using enum type. In addition I wanted to change cursor type over root window when controller state is changed but for some reason the cursor is not changed as expected. Below I attached sample code representing the problem. I have Windows 10 on my PC. I also tried to change cursor type in state setter method of Controller class but it also did not work.

```
from enum import Enum
import tkinter as tk

# enum with controller states
class APP_STATE(Enum):
    BUSY = 1
    IDLE = 0

# main window of the application    
class MainWnd(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        super(MainWnd, self).__init__()
        
        # initialize
        self.title('TEST')
        
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Start Long Running Event", command=self.controller.create_document)
        button.pack()

# context manager used to manage states of the controller
class ControllerManager:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

    def __enter__(self):
        self.parent.state = APP_STATE.BUSY
        print("cursor is {0}".format(self.parent.appInstance.cget("cursor")))
        self.parent.appInstance.config(cursor="wait")
        self.parent.appInstance.update()
        print("cursor should be wait and is {0}".format(self.parent.appInstance.cget("cursor")))

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.parent.state = APP_STATE.IDLE
        print("cursor is {0}".format(self.parent.appInstance.cget("cursor")))
        self.parent.appInstance.config(cursor="")
        print("cursor should be default and is {0}".format(self.parent.appInstance.cget("cursor")))

        
class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._state = APP_STATE.IDLE # state
        self.appInstance = MainWnd(self) # app window

        
    @property
    def state(self):
        return self._state
    
    @state.setter
    def state(self, new_value):
        if new_value == APP_STATE.BUSY:
            self._state = new_value
        elif new_value == APP_STATE.IDLE:
            self._state = new_value
    #######################################
    def run(self):
        self.appInstance.mainloop()
        
    #######################################      
    def create_document(self): # some long running task
        with ControllerManager(self):
            import time
            time.sleep(2)
            print("Task completed") 
     
cl = Controller()
cl.run()
```

Above-mentioned code shows that the cursor is changed but visually I don't see it on the screen when code is executing. I suspect that something is blocking tkinter config() and update() functions but I don't know how to change it to make it works. Addtionally, I made some tests with similar code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class CursorManager:
    def __init__(self, widget, cursor_type):
        self.widget = widget
        self.cursor_type = cursor_type

    def __enter__(self):
        self.widget.config(cursor=self.cursor_type)

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.widget.config(cursor="")  # Reset cursor to default

# Create a Tkinter root window
root = tk.Tk()

def execute_task():
    # Use the CursorManager as a context manager to change the cursor
    with CursorManager(button, "watch"):
        # Simulate a long-running task
        import time
        time.sleep(2)
        print("Task completed")

# Create a button that triggers the task execution
button = tk.Button(root, text="Execute Task", command=execute_task)

# Display the button and start the Tkinter event loop
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

In this case it works like expected but I don't fully understand why it works fine when ealier example does not work. I am missing something but don knwo what exacly it is.

Comment: If a `time.sleep()` is running, then Tkinter *isn't* running, and your cursor changes are irrelevant.  A running event loop is required to respond to the cursor moving into/out of a widget with a different cursor setting.

Comment: @jasonharper then why for the second example it works?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I experimented with threads and come up with working solution. Unfortunately it is not too elegant, but I don't have better idea how to make it work. I still don't fully understand why example 1 from my question does not work and example 2 works. So, my solution is to use context manager in separate thread, then tkinter mainloop is not blocked apparently. Here is working example:

```
from enum import Enum
import tkinter as tk
import threading
from contextlib import contextmanager

class APP_STATE(Enum):
    BUSY = 1
    IDLE = 0
    
class MainWnd(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        super(MainWnd, self).__init__()
        
        # initialize
        self.title('TEST')
        
        button = tk.Button(self, text="Start Long Running Event", command=self.controller.create_document)
        button.pack()

class ControllerManager:
    def __init__(self, widget, cursor):
        self.cursor = cursor
        self.widget = widget
        
    def __enter__(self):
        print("ok")
        self.widget.config(cursor=self.cursor)
        
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.widget.config(cursor="")

class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._state = APP_STATE.IDLE
        self.appInstance = MainWnd(self)

    #######################################
    def run(self):
        self.appInstance.mainloop()
        
    #######################################      
    def create_document(self):
        def long_ops():
            with ControllerManager(self.appInstance, "wait"):
                import time
                time.sleep(4)
                print("Task completed")   
        work_thread = threading.Thread(target=long_ops)
        work_thread.start()
```